# paypal order summary empty on mobile

Tags: mobile, paypal

I couldn't find any similar questions (most dealt with broken form posts) but this is not the case.

I have a paypal form that works flawlessly on desktop/laptop. On mobile devices I successfully get to paypal but there is nothing in the order summary, as if nothing got posted to paypal. A variable dump shows all form variables are in place, so I'm quite confused.

Here is the form I submit:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" id="myRegister">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="service@obscured.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Some description.">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="5.00">  
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1248" />
<input type="hidden" name="cbt" value="Click This Button To Register." />
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://mydomain/redirect.cfm" />
</form>
```

And that works on Desktop. I am just trying to get it work within a phone browser at the moment. I'll deal with the Paypal phone app at another time, if needed.

Any help appreciated.

Edit: This is also happening with PayPal hosted Buy It Now buttons as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within Android browser settings, clear setting for individual websites: Settings > Content Settings  > Website Settings. Select paypal.com.  Apparently there was a issue that was not resolved just by clearing the browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me on mobile, I can see the order details by tapping the "My total". The details are hidden at the first place though, I have to tap to make it show, seems it's designed this way

Comment: Thanks yihui. I cannot find that option anywhere in my paypal interface, though. Was that within the paypal app or the mobile website? Thanks again.

Comment: Okay... after clearing cache and settings related to paypal on my phone it now works. Thanks for confirming it was not the code @yihui !